# Permanent SSH tunnel through bastion host

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, macos, tunneling

I have the following command that I run locally on my mac to be able to access a DB server trough a bastion host:

```
ssh -L 9234:MYSERVERIP:5432  USER@MYBASTIONIP -i MyBastionPemKey.pem
```

that works just fine, I can connect to it using localhost:9234

I would like to have that tunnel permanently open. I Know there are tools like autossh, but only encountered simple examples (without the bastion part) and I cant fins a way of doing it using the ~/.ssh/config file on mac

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve the above?

Comment: What do you mean by “permanent”? It’s fairly straight forward to manually kick off a tunnel in the background which stays running until it is stopped by reboot or log off.  But you’d have to remember to start it each time.  If you wanted something with less manual involvement, you probably need to look at `launchd`, or it might suffice to put something in your shell profile, but would need to handle checking for already running tunnel.